# Google Transliterate API for hinglish to hindi is not working

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-docs-api, google-translation-api

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Type in Hindi (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)<br>
    <textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using this code from [Google Transliterate API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started#hiworld)  but this code is not working please Help me to solve this.

I am search an API for Hinglish to hindi and i found Google Transliterate API [getting_started](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started)
and I took a sample of code from this website. However code is not working an error got in web browser.

Please  help me to improve my skills to make websites work as soon as possible.

Comment: **this code is not working** does not properly describe your issue.  What is your error exactly?

Comment: What error messages do you get when you run your code?